# Why there is no error raised by compiler?

Tags: java

I just found my compiler allowed me to write below code and did not raised any compile time error. Could anyone please enlighten me!

```
double y = arcToFindPointOn.getCenterXY().y - arcToFindPointOn.getRadius()*Math.sin(theta);;
```

Weird thing about above code line is semi-colon at the very end!

Thanks!

Comment: *"Why there is no error raised by compiler?"* Because it's [not an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545375/why-there-is-no-error-raised-by-compiler/7545399#7545399). ;-)

Comment: @T.J., Yeah I know that lol, but felt so weird while looking at it!it's like there are 10,000 things dosent work in application and it's all because of this silly thing. but Davide Piras answered very well and now I can proceed my debugging :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in other languages as well, like C# and C++, having an instruction with only `;` means empty instruction and is allowed, generates no errors and simply does nothing.

plenty of articles on this online, found this one: [Multiple semicolons are allowed by the C# Compiler for statement termination](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/92867/multiple-semicolons-are-allowed-by-the-c-compiler-for-statement-termination)

> This is a little weirdness inherited from C. In fact your example
>   isn't a statement terminated by three semicolons, but three
>   statements, two of which are empty. Occassionally it can be useful to
>   use the empty statement in e.g. an if statement or a while loop, and
>   then it would seem arbitrary to disallow it elsewhere. Besides,
>   changing it now would be an unnecessary breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

Java also allows for the [empty statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.6):

```
;
```

which actually does nothing at all. In your example you just have one at the very end.

Answer (score -1):

The ";" is a delimiter, so the compiler can safely ignore the blank statement. However some IDEs help you optimize code and will not let you get away with this statement.

Comment: Removing an empty statement does not "optimize the code" because the empty statement has no impact on runtime performance whatsoever.  What the IDE is doing is *suggesting* a tidy up and pointing out a *possible* error in your code.